# Why doesn't ISO c++17 permit a structured binding declaration in a condition?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Clang emits a warning if I use a structured binding declaration as a condition:

```cpp
$ cat hello.cc
int main() {
  struct A { int i; operator bool() { return true; } };
  if (auto [i] = A{0}) {
    return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

```
$ clang++-10 -std=c++17 hello.cc
hello.cc:3:12: warning: ISO C++17 does not permit structured binding declaration in a condition [-Wbinding-in-condition]                                                                                                                                                                               
  if (auto [i] = A{0}) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
           ^~~                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
1 warning generated.
```

I don't see this in [dcl.struct.bind](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.struct.bind) or [stmt.select](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.select); where would I see that this is forbidden?

Furthermore: what is the rationale behind forbidding this?

Comment: It is less of what the language permits and more of what people programming the compiler have had time and energy to do. C++ is a shockingly difficult programming language to compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver Got caught on the same thing, structured binding here is the `condition`, not `init-statement`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yep.  `if (auto [i] = A{0}; i)` works just fine.  I forgot that without an explicit condition the `init-statement` becomes the condition.

Comment: Ok, when there's only one element, it could've been the condition. But what do you expect a multi-element binding to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The grammar for the if statement is

```
if constexpr(opt) ( init-statement(opt) condition) statement
```

and as you can see `condition` is required while the `init-statement` is optional.  That means in `if (auto [i] = A{0})` that `auto [i] = A{0}` is the condition, not the `init-statment`.  [`condition`](https://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.pre#nt:condition) is defined as

```
condition:
    expression
    attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq declarator brace-or-equal-initializer
```

and that does not allow for a structured binding as the [grammar for that](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.pre#nt:simple-declaration) is

```
attribute-specifier-seq(opt) decl-specifier-seq ref-qualifier(opt) [ identifier-list ] initializer ;
```

---

Good news is you can get what you want by adding a condition to your if statement like

```
if (auto [i] = A{0}; i)
```

Comment: I'm accepting this answer since it addresses the core question. Just for the record: the members of the tuple don't encode the truthiness in this case, so I guess the workaround needs to be a wrapper which evaluates the initial tuple's truthiness then pushes it as a member of a new tuple.